# Lambda Expression is not working, getting terminated

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-interface

wrote java8 program with lambda expression, its not getting executed instead its getting terminated at the lambda expression, no exceptions

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.function.BiConsumer;

    public class BiConsumerTest {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{


        List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();

        list1.add("A");
        list1.add("B");
        list1.add("V");


    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();

        list2.add("J");
        list2.add("G");
        list2.add("P");

        BiConsumer<List<String>  , List<String>> bc = (lista, listb) ->{
                lista.stream().forEach( System.out::print);

            };


        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

expected is it will print the string in list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you're not calling the `BiConsumer`'s `accept` method. call it as follows:

```
  bc.accept(list1, list2);
```

Further, note that it's not necessary to call `stream` just to call `forEach` instead call `forEach` directly on the list:

```
 lista.forEach(System.out::print);
```

Another thing is that your `BiConsumer` doesn't use the second list, this may be because you haven't finished implementing the entire logic yet in which case it's understandable.

Complete code:

```
BiConsumer<List<String>, List<String>> bc = (lista, listb) -> {
    lista.forEach(System.out::print);
    // listb.forEach(System.out::print);
};
bc.accept(list1, list2);
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, could you please give me the entire syntax , I mean entire line with the code

Comment: for bc.accept(list1, list2); where should i call the lambda expression I am not getting

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

You've currently just defined the functional interface, to execute it further you need to invoke the implementation in your code. In your case, for this, you need to call the [`BiConsumer.accept`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/BiConsumer.html#accept(T,U)) method as:

```
bc.accept(list1, list2);
```

which then performs the operation, you've defined. As its Javadoc states

> Performs this operation on the given arguments.

---

On another note, if I was to suggest, you might just be intending to print(at least) both the lists that you are consuming as :

```
BiConsumer<List<String>, List<String>> biConsumer = (lista, listb) -> {
    lista.forEach(System.out::print);
    listb.forEach(System.out::print);
};
biConsumer.accept(list1, list2);
```

which would print as an output *`A B V J G P`*.

(From comments) This could further be written as :

```
BiConsumer<List<String>, List<String>> biConsumer =
                      (lista, listb) -> Stream.concat(lista.stream(), listb.stream())
                                              .forEach( System.out::print);
```

Comment: `bc = (lista, listb) -> Stream.concat(lista.stream(),listb.stream()).forEach( System.out::print);`

Comment: @HadiJ Well, agreed. Just that IMHO this question wasn't about the compute part. Thanks for the suggestion anyway.